# Odoo 10 - procurement_id in stock_moves

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

While trying to understand Odoo model for delivery slips I have realized that some stock_moves rows do have procurement_id populated and others do not.

Why is this? When is procurement_id populated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Procurement_id is populated when the stock move is generated by a procurement. Stock moves created by a sale order are created throught a procurement. A stock move created by purchase order will not have a procurement id because purchase orders do not create stock moves.